# Hide uinavigation Leftbar button

Tags: iphone

i am try for hide uinavigationbar Leftbarbutton

```
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.hidden = YES;

 self.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.hidden =YES;
```

I write this code but it is not work for me any body know about it.

Answer (score 3):

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```